# How to enable CORS for SonarQube service

Tags: cors, sonarqube

I am trying to call one of Sonar web-service through jQuery. Since the call is going across domain, the call is failing on Chrome with following error:
  **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**
Do anyone know how to enable CORS on SonarQube server? I am using SonarQube 4.3. I even tried adding the filter in sonarqube-4.3\web\WEB-INF\web.xml but it did not help. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
    <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
    <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
    <param-value>10</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Thanks,
Sara

Answer (score 3):

I have fallen on the same issue.

To get rid of this one, just set the initialization parameter **`resetUnhandledResponse`** of the [`RackFilter`](https://github.com/jruby/jruby-rack) to `false` in the `web.xml` file of Sonar.

The settings of the CORS filter should then work as it should wherever you define it, at the server or at the application level.

```
<filter>
 <filter-name>RackFilter</filter-name>
 <filter-class>org.jruby.rack.RackFilter</filter-class>
 <init-param>
    <param-name>resetUnhandledResponse</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value> <!-- true (default), false or buffer -->
 </init-param>
</filter>
```

Comment: This is wrong. It has stopped my server from running

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who are still looking for an answer to this question, please checkout [this link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sonarqube/FGWQWEdR_PU/G0GpH6GzBAAJ). The solution is to enable CORS for your catalina server that Sonarqube runs on.